# Gift Certificates

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The door prizes at a charity concert are: 8 - \$20 gift certificates 5 - \$40 gift certificates 5 - \$60 gift certificates 6- \$100 gift certificates. Just before the concert starts, the prize envelopes are mixed in a bag and ten prizes are drawn at random. a)What is the probability that none of the ten pre-concert prizes is a \$20 gift certificate? b) What is the probability that exactly four or five prizes with a value greater than $40 are drawn?

I'm stuck on part b of this question, I've included my work below but I'm unsure if its correct. I've done it two different ways and have two different answers. Can someone please help?

Both methods are in the following link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GlkH.jpg

Comment: Please type in your attempt. Images can't be read by all.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.